# simple SQL query not working (emp,dept)

Tags: sql

the database contains the famous Oracle simple tables (dept,emp)

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT (
 DEPTNO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
 DNAME               CHAR(14),
 LOC                 CHAR(13));

CREATE TABLE EMP (
 EMPNO               NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
 ENAME               CHAR(10),
 JOB                 CHAR(9),
 MGR                 NUMBER(4) ,
 HIREDATE            DATE,
 SAL                 NUMBER(7,2),
 COMM                NUMBER(7,2),
 DEPTNO              NUMBER(2) NOT NULL );
```

Question : Find the total of Commissions for Employees according to different jobs (including 0 )

how it should be done ?

Comment: Homework by any chance?

Comment: When you said not working (that too a simple query), you should have tried something. Where is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT JOB, SUM(NVL(COMM,0)) AS TOTAL_COMM
FROM
EMP
GROUP BY JOB
```

Comment: Thanks man :) I didn't know the command nvl , and one more thing , if I wrote the same code you wrote but without "AS" does it make a difference ?

Comment: `AS` is used to assign an alias name to the computed column `SUM(NVL(COMM,0))`

Comment: I know .. But does it make a difference if I don't type it ?  Will it still assign the alias without typing "AS"?

Comment: no, even if you dont type as, it will assign the name TOTAL_COMM - `SELECT JOB, SUM(NVL(COMM,0)) TOTAL_COMM
FROM
EMP
GROUP BY JOB` this will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Here I try to get job wise Commission of Employee...

`Select JOB, sum(ISNULL(comm,0)) from Emp
Group by Job`